# Initialize object to show in my Scaffold

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a Flutter app and I stopped on a problem and I hope that you guys can help me.

First of all, english is not my first language, so I'm sorry for any typo.

I'm coding a simple 'Manage Profile' screen. When the user register on my app I show to him a Scaffold with some fields that has to be filled, like Name, Surname, email and so on.

I'm using Firestore database and that's the async method I'm calling for retrieve an 'User' object:

```
  Future<Usuario> getUsuarioLogado() async {
    Cartao cartao;
    String email = await auth.currentUser();
    String nome, sobrenome, cpf, numeroCartao, nomeCartao;

    DocumentReference usuarioReference =
        Firestore.instance.document('Usuarios/' + email);

    usuarioReference.get().then((datasnapshot) {
      if (datasnapshot.exists) {
        nome = datasnapshot.data['nome'];
        sobrenome = datasnapshot.data['sobrenome'];
        cpf = datasnapshot.data['cpf'];

        CollectionReference cartaoReference =
            Firestore.instance.collection('Usuarios/' + email + '/Cartao');

        cartaoReference.getDocuments().then((cartoes) {
          List listCartoes = cartoes.documents;
          nomeCartao = listCartoes[0].data['nome'];
          numeroCartao = listCartoes[0].data['numero'];

          cartao = new Cartao(nomeCartao, numeroCartao);
          return new Usuario(cpf, nome, sobrenome, email, cartao);
        }).catchError((e) {
          print('#ANTLOG_GET_CARTAO: ' + e);
        });
      }
      return new Usuario(cpf, nome, sobrenome, email, cartao);
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('#ANTLOG_GET_USUARIO: ' + e);
    });
  }
```

The code above is working when I debug but it not return the object when I need. The moment is when my screen is building itself.

After reading some foruns I tried to return a FutureBuilder that will only show the content if the 'Usuarios' (Users) isn't empty.

```
return FutureBuilder<Usuario>(
  future: perfil.getUsuarioLogado(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Usuario> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      print('#ANTLOG: ${snapshot.data}');
      return scaffold;
    } else
      return Text('Loading...');
  },
);
```

The code below throws me a null value:

```
print('#ANTLOG: ${snapshot.data}');
```

I was wondering how can I obligate the screen to wait until I have my 'Usuarios' object. Seems like that the FutureBuilder is not working or I'm doing something wrong.

Please I need your help.

Comment: try instead of `snapshot.connectionState == done` to use `snapshot.hasData`

Comment: @RémiRousselet, now the screen is always in the `Loading...` screen

Comment: There's most likely an error in your loading. Therefore `hasData` is always false

Comment: My snapshot will retrieve data sometime but the `return` method is called and it has no data. Can I add some Listener to get the snapshot object so that I can reload my Scaffold with this retrieved data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FutureBuilder` has a property named `initialData` you can use it to put your initial empty object.

Also as Rémi Rousselet mentioned, you should use snapshot.hasData to check if there are data available

```
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
      print('#ANTLOG: ${snapshot.data}');
      return scaffold;
    } else
      return Text('Loading...');
  },
```

And because your method is marked as `async`, use `await` keyword before `usuarioReference.get()`  to wait for the response , your code will be more readable in that way.

```
 await usuarioReference.get()  ...
```

the same for

```
 await cartaoReference.getDocuments()
```

Comment: I can't use `await` in my Future parameter of FutureBuilder cause Dart throws an error.

Comment: I thought that when I use the FutureBuilder in my return it will wait until my `perfil.getUsuarioLogado()` return something. But it is executed just one time and my object has no data. I wish I could reload the Scaffold when my FutureBuilder retrieve my data

Comment: final  datasnapshot  = await usuarioReference.get();    //inside your methods instead of using  then()...

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I have replaced my two `.then` with a final. That's how it looks like: `final snapshot = await usuarioReference.get();`. Now my method is waiting and will only show my Scaffold when the data is received. Can you please explain to me why the `final` makes my Async to wait the result?

Comment: the final keyword is not important, just the  await (FutureTask) ,  instead of  (FutureTask).then ....

Comment: you can use:   var snapshot = await usuarioReference.get();    and it will work

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, this will help me a lot in my journey of Flutter

Comment: no problem, watch this video when you can and you'll learn more about async in dart:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUDOIAssBDs